# Why does my code work when inserting it inside componentDidMount lifecycle (reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use chartist.js with my react component. I have downloaded the chartist.js from the link mentioned below. I have downloaded the chartist folder and saved it inside my react project.

When I insert this line -> `const mychart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);`

inside `componentDidMount()` function I am able to see the chart on web page.

Chartist.js -> https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/

Line.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var data = {
  // A labels array that can contain any sort of values
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
  series: [
    [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
  ]
};

const mychart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data); <---- Line 10

class Line extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth">
              {mychart}
          </div>
      </div>
    )}
}

export default Line;
```

Parent component:

```
render(){
   return(
     <div>
        <Line/>
     </div>
)
}
```

Above Line component gives error in console saying -> `cannot read property querySelectorAll` Now when I add `Line 10` of Pie component inside `componentDidMount()` function my Line component works fine and it also render's component on web page but I could not understand why does it work on inserting that `line 10` inside `componentDidMount()` function.

Below code works why but ?

```
componentDidMount(){
    const mychart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);
}
```

Screenshot error (Note: In screenshot below Pie component is basically my Line component in above code):

[image]

Comment: Pie component? Where's that code?

Comment: Because in your first snippet the `ct-chart` element isn't mounted and thus not accessible via `querySelectorAll` (it doesn't exist in the DOM yet) when you call `Chartist.Line`.

Comment: @MarkC. Sorry Pie component is Line component basically.

Comment: @Li357 Ok so you mean when the component is mounted then only it should create new Chartist object am I right ?

Comment: @stonerock Yes, because `Chartist.Line` tries to select the element with the selector you passed on construction. It will not exist unless your component is mounted hence why it works in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in React docs, componentDidMount() is used for those initializations that require the DOM nodes. `new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);` clearly uses an DOM element.

As a suggestion you might try [react-chartist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartist) that is a "React component for Chartist.js".

Cheers!

Comment: Yes I know about `react-chartist` but I have downloaded chartist.js folder from their github repo because `react-chartist` is just a wrapper around chartist.js.

Comment: @stonerock it is jus a wrapper but that wrapper is handling the bootstrapping and lifecycle events for you. you can just build your own wrapping layer to do so if you don't want another node module :)